# Exercise 7, Section 3.3 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, vector-space-isomorphism

> Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over the field $F$ and let $U$ be an isomorphism of $V$ onto $W$. Prove that $T \to UTU^{−1}$ is an isomorphism of $L(V, V)$ onto $L(W, W)$.

**My attempt:** $f:L(V,V)\to L(W,W)$ is defined by $f(T)=U\circ T\circ U^{-1}$. Let $T,L\in L(V,V)$. Then $f(T+L)$ $=U\circ (T+L)\circ U^{-1}$. We need to show $U\circ (T+L)\circ U^{-1}$ $= U\circ T\circ U^{-1} + U\circ L\circ U^{-1}$. Let $y\in W$. So $U\circ (T+L)\circ U^{-1}(y)$ $= U[ (T+L)( U^{-1}(y))]$ $=U[T(U^{-1}(y))+L(U^{-1}(y))]$. Since $U$ is a linear map, we have $U[T(U^{-1}(y))+L(U^{-1}(y))]$ $=U(T(U^{-1}(y)))+U(L(U^{-1}(y)))$ $=U\circ T\circ U^{-1}(y) +U\circ L\circ U^{-1}(y)$ $= (U\circ T\circ U^{-1} + U\circ L\circ U^{-1})(y)$. Hence $U\circ (T+L)\circ U^{-1}$ $= U\circ T\circ U^{-1} + U\circ L\circ U^{-1}$ $=f(T+L)$ $=f(T)+f(L)$.

Let $c\in F$ and $T\in L(V,V)$. Then $f(c\cdot T)=U\circ (c\cdot T)\circ U^{-1}$. We need to show $U\circ (c\cdot T)\circ U^{-1}$ $=c\cdot (U\circ T\circ U^{-1})$. Let $y\in W$. So $U\circ (c\cdot T)\circ U^{-1}(y)$ $=U[(c\cdot T)(U^{-1}(y))]$ $=U(c\cdot T(U^{-1}(x)))$. Since $U$ is linear map, we have $U(c\cdot T(U^{-1}(x))$ $=c\cdot U(T(U^{-1}(y)))$ $=c\cdot (U\circ T\circ U^{-1})(y)$. Hence $U\circ (cT)\circ U^{-1}$ $=c(U\circ T\circ U^{-1})$ $=f(cT)$ $=c\cdot f(T)$. I didn’t make distinction for addition and scalar multiplication for different vector spaces, because there are total $4$ vector space: $V$, $W$, $L(V,W)$ and $L(W,W)$.

There are two ways to show $f$ is bijective, $(1)$ $f$ is injective and surjective, $(2)$ $f$ is invertible, i.e. $\exists g:L(W,W)\to L(V,V)$ such that $g\circ f=\text{id}_{L(V,V)}$ and $f\circ g=\text{id}_{L(W,W)}$.

**Approach(1):** If $f(T)=f(L)$, for some $T,L\in L(V,V)$. Then $U\circ T\circ U^{-1}$ $=U\circ L\circ U^{-1}$. We need to show $T=L$, i.e. $T(x)=L(x)$, $\forall x\in V$. Let $x\in V$. Since $U:V\to W$ is invertible, we have $\exists !$$y\in W$ such that $U^{-1}(y)=x$. So $U(T(U^{-1}(y)))$ $=U(L(U^{-1}(y)))$ $=U(T(x))$ $=U(L(x))$. Since $U$ is injective, we have $T(x)=L(x)$. Hence $T=L$. Another way to show $f$ is injective is $N_{L(V,V)}$ $=\{T\in L(V,V)| f(T)=0\}$ $=\{0\}$. Again I didn’t make any distinction for zero vector for different vector spaces. If $f(T)=0$, for some $T\in L(V,V)$. Then $U\circ T\circ U^{-1}=0$. We need to show $T=0$, i.e. $T(x)=0$, $\forall x\in V$. So $U(T(U^{-1}(W)))=\{0\}$. Since $U:V\to W$ is invertible, we have $U^{-1}(W)=V$. So $U(T(U^{-1}(W)))$ $=U(T(V))$ $=\{0\}$. Since $U$ is injective, i.e. $N_U=\{0\}$, we have $T(V)=\{0\}$. Thus $T=0$. Hence $T$ is injective.

Let $Z\in L(W,W)$. Take $T=U^{-1}\circ Z\circ U \in L(V,V)$. Then $f(T)=U\circ (U^{-1}\circ Z\circ U)\circ U^{-1}$. It’s easy to check, composition is associative. so $U\circ (U^{-1}\circ Z\circ U)\circ U^{-1}$ $= (U\circ U^{-1})\circ Z\circ (U\circ U^{-1})$ $=\text{id}_W \circ Z\circ \text{id}_W$ $= \text{id}_W\circ Z$ $=Z$. Thus $\exists T\in L(V,V)$ such that $f(T)=Z$. Hence $f$ is surjective. So $f$ is bijective.

**Approach(2):** We show $f$ is invertible, i.e. $\exists g:L(W,W)\to L(V,V)$ such that $f\circ g=\text{id}_{L(W,W)}$ and $g\circ f=\text{id}_{L(V,V)}$. Define $g:L(W,W)\to L(V,V)$ such that $g(Z)=U^{-1}\circ Z\circ U$. It’s easy to check $U^{-1}\circ Z\circ U:V\to V$. By theorem 6 section 3.2, $U^{-1}\circ Z\circ U$ is a linear map. So $g$ is a well defined map. Let $Z\in L(W,W)$. Then $f\circ g(Z)$ $=f(g(Z))$ $=f(U^{-1}\circ Z\circ U)$ $=Z$. Hence $f\circ g=\text{id}_{L(W,W)}$. Let $T\in L(V,V)$. Then $g\circ f(T)$ $=g(f(T))$ $=g(U\circ T\circ U^{-1})$ $=T$. Hence $g\circ f=\text{id}_{L(V,V)}$. So $f$ is invertible, i.e. bijective. **Is my proof correct?**

**Question:** In approach(2), it seems like we didn’t use full strength of $V\cong W$, mainly $U$ is bijective. Similarly in proof (subjective part) of approach(1), it seems like we didn’t use $U$ is bijective. In proof (injective part) of approach(1), we explicitly use $U$ is bijective. Before writing proof, I was thinking, I have to use injective condition of $U$ to show $f$ is injective and surjective condition of $U$ to show $f$ is surjective. But that is not the case, I think.

Comment: For $U : V \to W$: (1) there is a function $f_1 : W \to V$ such that $U \circ f_1 = \mathrm{id}_W$ if and only if $U$ is surjective; (2) there is a function $f_2 : W \to V$ such that $f_2 \circ U = \mathrm{id}_V$ if and only if $U$ is injective.  You use this repeatedly through all parts, which is where all the assumptions come in.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes. Without bijective condition of $U$, writing $U^{-1}$ don’t make sense.

Comment: If that comment doesn't answer your question, then I think you need to clarify what your question is.  For instance, showing $f$ is injective only needs to use the assumption $U$ is injective; similarly, showing $f$ is surjective only needs to use the assumption $U$ is surjective.  Combine that with the theorem that $U$ linear and bijective means the function $U^{-1}$ is linear and you have the "full strength of $V \cong W$" in the proof.  If instead you're saying the proof applies more broadly in any algebraic theory that has that type of theorem, then yes, that's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V, W$ : two finite dimensional vector spaces over $F$ .

$T\in \mathcal{L}(V) $ and $U\in\mathcal{L}(W) $

Given $U\in \mathcal{L}(V, W) $ is an isomorphism i.e an invertible linear map. Then it follows that $V\cong W$

Hence $\mathcal{L}(V) $ and $\mathcal{L}(W)$ are same dimensional vector spaces over $F$.

Let us consider $\varphi:\mathcal{L}(V)\to \mathcal{L}(W)$ defined by$$ \varphi(T )=UTU^{−1}$$

Then

$\varphi$ is a linear map.

$\begin{align}\ker \varphi &=\{T\in\mathcal{L}(V): \varphi(T)=\textbf{0}\}\\&=\{   T\in\mathcal{L}(V) : UTU^{-1}=\textbf{0} \}\\&= \{\textbf{0}\} \end{align}$

A linear map between two same finite dimensional linear spaces is injective iff surjective iff invertible.

Hence $\varphi$ is an isomorphism between
$\mathcal{L}(V) $ and $\mathcal{L}(W)$

---

Note:

1. Suppose  $V, W$ are not finite dimensional .

We use finite dimensionality of $V, W$ to prove $\varphi$ is injective iff surjective iff bijective.

In general we need to show $\phi$ is injective as well as surjective.

Let us take $S\in \mathcal{L}(W) $ .

Then we need to find a $T\in \mathcal{L}(V) $ such that $\varphi(T) =S$

i.e $UTU^{-1}=S$ implies $T=U^{-1}SU$

$U^{-1}SU$ is the required preimage as $\varphi(U^{-1}SU) = UU^{-1}SUU^{-1}=S$

2. First half of the proof is enough to conclude $\varphi$ is an isomorphism even when vector spaces are infinite dimensional.Because the proof injective iff surjective depends on Rank-Nullity theorem and we can also restore Rank-Nullity theorem for infinite dimensional vector spaces upto cardinality.(interesting!)

Comment: This works in the finite dimensional setting but the question isn't about that, however.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I think $U\circ T\circ U^{-1}=0$  implies $T=0$, need more justification. Or is it obvious?

Comment: Obvious as $U$ is invertible

Comment: @Abhi still have any issue?

Comment: I showed $U$ is injective in two ways. Both of them is pretty long. Can you tell, where it can be condense?

Comment: $U$ is an isomorphism i.e a invertible linear map. So it must be injective.

Comment: I don’t still see why it’s obvious.

Comment: $U$ is injective? Isn't follows from definition?

Comment: What is the definition of an isomorphism? Existence of an invertible linear mal. Isn't it?

Comment: Ohhhh…….. I think I get it. Suppose $U\circ T\circ U^{-1}=0$. Since $U$ is injective, $T(U^{-1}(W))=T(V)=\{0\}$. Hence $T=0$.

Comment: Nice nice. It's interesting that Rank-Nullity Theorem holds even in the infinite dimensional setting. I haven't seen many linear algebra texts that bother to discuss it in that setting at all.

Comment: @LostinSpace Is my above proof of injectivity same as you have in your mind and can you please elaborate more on “we can also restore Rank-Nullity theorem for infinite dimensional vector spaces upto cardinality”? What do you mean by, upto cardinality?

Comment: It's difficult to explain. For infinite dimensional vector space, there are different kind of basis. One is algebraic basis (Hamel basis) , topological basis (Schauder basis). Do you know cardinal arithmetic? Dimension for finite dimensional vector space is number of elements in a basis. It's easy to count. But for infinite dimensional vector space, dimension( hamel dimension) is the cardinality of  a basis. For an example the vector space of all sequences which are eventually $0$ are of dimension $\aleph_0$ .

Comment: For infinite dimensional vector space we can also extend rank nullity theorem even when the dimension of ker and image are infinite and algebraic sum of dimension is the cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: @LostinSpace I don’t know anything about cardinal arithmetic, Hamel basis, etc. I’m so sorry to insist you to reply.